# How to extract specific emails from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, text, extract

New to python and stuck on this!

I have a large text file of just emails from various domains. Say I want to pull out just gmail AND hotmail.

I was able to with this but it comes out all mixed together.

```
filename = input('Enter filename to open: ')
try:
    filename = open(filename)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened: ', filename)
exit()
import re
for line in filename:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('\S+@gmail.com',  line)
    if len(x) > 0:
        print(x)
    y = re.findall('\S+@hotmail.com',  line)
    if len(y) > 0:
        print(y)
```

My goal is to have it print out all the gmail emails and then list the number of gmail email addresses it found. Then I would like it to list all the hotmail accounts and list how many hotmail accounts it found. Make sense?

Comment: I think it's because you're searching line by line. That means that it'll print the gmail addresses in the line and then the hotmail addresses in the line, then move on to the next line. Instead of printing all the gmail addresses in the file and then all the hotmail addresses in the file.

Unless that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Consider using module `mailbox` (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/mailbox.html) instead of messing up with mail messages yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JAW is absolutely correct about the problem being that you’re searching it line by line. Since you’re using `re.findall`, there’s no reason for why you will need to iterate through the lines. All you have to do is this:

```
import re

filename = input('Enter filename to open: ')

try:
    file = open(filename)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened: ', filename)
    exit()

emails = file.read()
x = re.findall('\S+@gmail.com',  emails)
if len(x) > 0:
    print(x)
    # or print("\n".join(x)) for list-like printing 

y = re.findall('\S+@hotmail.com',  emails)
if len(y) > 0:
    print(y)
    # or print("\n".join(y)) for list-like printing
```

Comment: Realized this doesn't print out the whole line. How would I go about doing that ?  The text files I'm looking at are typically only emails, sometimes containing passwords. I need to pull out the ones that have certain emails and then whatever else is on that line.

Comment: To make it simple and easy for you to work with, you can use grouping. `re.compile('(\S+@gmail.com) *(\w+)')`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of printing the addresses as you find them, collect them in two lists and print the lists at the end:

```
gmail = []
hotmail = []

for line in filename: #filename is a BAD name for this variable
    address = re.findall('\S+@gmail.com', line)
    if address: gmail.extend(address)
    address = re.findall('\S+@hotmail.com', line)
    if address: hotmail.extend(address)

print(gmail)
print(hotmail)
```